# Starting a detached screen has no effect

Tags: ubuntu, cron, gnu-screen

I want to start a shell script in detached mode on ubuntu bootup (via cronjob @reboot) but it doesn't even work when I try it directly.

Syntax:

```
screen -d -m -S myscreenname /path/to/my/script.sh
```

There is no feedback at all and no screen is being opened. I did not find any active process as well. I also tried it without -S and the name or with different commands.

Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the script terminates, the screen session will terminate as well. That is most likely what is happening. Inserting a command in the script to touch a new file somewhere could confirm that the script is actually being started.

Comment: Or even better - add some `read` to the script. That force him await for some user interaction and `screen` stay running until user press <enter>